# How can we get exact time to load all the links using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can we get exact time to load all the links using selenium webdriver?

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.get("Some url");
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);
```

This code works fine for the home page(example.com) but suppose i want to find load time of pages available under example.com. Is this possible. I am new to code so any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Selenium is really the right tool for this job. Selenium doesn't wait for the page to load completely before returning control to you so your times won't be accurate. You can try waiting for an element that you know is on the page you want to time but even then that element may be available before the page has finished loading completely.

Best thing to do would be use a tool designed for that purpose, such as [Pingdon's tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)

Answer (score 0):

I use Webdriver in a .NET environment and attach HttpWatch to my tests to record client side performance data. If you are using Java you should be able to use BrowserMob proxy to capture your required performance data, It will save the performance data in HTML Archive (HAR) format.

[BrowserMob proxy website](http://bmp.lightbody.net/)